# install goose for golang and heroku

Tags: heroku, go, goose

I've tried 2 methods to include goose to my golang project and it fails during the heroku build. I first tried this method: https://bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/

I added 2 packages to the vendor.json file:

```
    {
        "checksumSHA1": "rmNwGgFJAcDxUGF5yB/zqhQPxCA=",
        "path": "bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/cmd/goose",
        "revision": "8488cc47d90c8a502b1c41a462a6d9cc8ee0a895",
        "revisionTime": "2015-01-15T23:40:39Z"
    },
    {
        "checksumSHA1": "jdqLDQw64kBjkU7LPK7C+Qwj7W8=",
        "path": "bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/lib/goose",
        "revision": "8488cc47d90c8a502b1c41a462a6d9cc8ee0a895",
        "revisionTime": "2015-01-15T23:40:39Z"
    }
```

and got the error:

```
can't load package: package bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/cmd/goose: cannot find package "bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/cmd/goose" in any of:
/app/tmp/cache/go1.7.5/go/src/bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/cmd/goose (from $GOROOT)
/tmp/tmp.Pqgwxz8KyN/.go/src/bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/cmd/goose (from $GOPATH)
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app.
```

I then found these directions: https://bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/issues/55/heroku-instructions-no-longer-works-on-go

and tried updating my vendor file to include:

```
        "install": [
        "./...",
        "bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/cmd/goose"
    ]
```

I'm still getting the same error message above. Any thoughts?

edit: Here's the full error message:

```
-----> Go app detected
-----> Checking vendor/vendor.json file.
-----> Using go1.7.5
-----> Fetching any unsaved dependencies (govendor sync)
-----> Running: go install -v -tags heroku ./... vendor/bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/‌​cmd/goose 
can't load package: package vendor/bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/‌​cmd/goose: cannot find package "vendor/bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/\u200c\u200bcmd/goose" in any of:
    /app/tmp/cache/go1.7.5/go/src/vendor/bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/‌​cmd/goose (from $GOROOT)
    /tmp/tmp.IJd3qxVYqW/.go/src/vendor/bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/‌​cmd/goose (from $GOPATH)
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: How does your project use goose on heroku? Are you importing `../lib/goose` in one of your project's `*.go` files and using it there? Or are you trying to install `../cmd/goose` and run it as part of the heroku build process?

Comment: @mkopriva trying to install ../cmd/goose and run as part of the build process. Thanks for the response!

Comment: anyone have a guess?

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, you said `I added 2 packages to the vendor.json file:`, you do have the two packages in the vendor folder right? Or you just updated the vendor.json file but the two goose projects aren't in the vendor folder?

Comment: @mkopriva They are in the vendor folder folder, yes

Comment: hmm @jj1111 make sure `heroku.sync` is not set to `false`, if it's not `false` the buildpack runs `govendor sync` to download any missing dependencies, make sure `GO_INSTALL_PACKAGE_SPEC` env var is **unset**, otherwise `heroku.install` is ignored, check all messages that the buildpack prints out before the actual error and look for hints for what might be wrong... If none of that helps have a look at https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/blob/master/bin/compile#L368-L389 this is the part that is supposed install goose, it runs `go install -v` with the contents of `heroku.install`.

Comment: One more idea: in `heroku.install` try prefixing the goose package with vendor, e.g. `{"heroku":{"install":["vendor/bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/cmd/goose"]}}`. From [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14323#issuecomment-184891572) "On the go command line, paths are always interpreted relative to GOROOT/GOPATH roots, not vendor directories. The canonical path for a vendored package includes the .../vendor/ prefix even though source code-level import references do not."

Comment: @mkopriva - thanks for all the ideas! I updated my post to have the full error message being returned. relating to GO_INSTALL_PACKAGE_SPEC, I don't think this is the issue because the buildpack messages outputs 'Running: go install -v -tags heroku' so I don't think heroku.install is being ignored. I've tried updating the goose package with 'vendor' but so far no luck. Any chance the full error message I just posted sheds some more light? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Ok the `vendor/` prefix was not a good idea, tested it and it doesn't work for me either (http://imgur.com/jwVKbHg)... Can you show the full error message for when you run this without the `vendor/` prefix? (without that prefix it works fine for me http://imgur.com/m3ElunP but as you can see in this output it's prefixed with the project's path, that's done [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/blob/master/bin/compile#L52-L62))

Comment: Can you also provide the full output for when you run this with `heroku.install` containing only `./...` (this works for me as well, installing all vendor deps including goose http://imgur.com/uWgkK8M)

Comment: I solved this problem by forking the goose repo and creating a vendor.json file. Then I installed this instead of bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/cmd/goose. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: no problem, glad you got it working.